Error 0xc0000606 when trying to use WSL2
I am trying to switch from WSL1 to WSL2 on Windows 10 Pro but I get this error
D:\Users\superkogito>wsl --list --verbose
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Stopped         1
  Debian          Stopped         1

D:\Users\superkogito>wsl --set-version Debian 2
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes.
Error: 0xc0000606
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateVm/HCS/0xc0000606

Here are my systems specs:

Windows:

> cmd /c ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4412]


WSL:

> wsl --version
WSL version: 2.3.24.0
Kernel version: 5.15.153.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.65
MSRDC version: 1.2.5620
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.26100.1-240331-1435.ge-release
Windows version: 10.0.19045.4412


Installation: I am not sure but probably using

> wsl --install


Startup mode



Hardware virtualisation: enabled



I am trying to switch from WSL1 to WSL2 on Windows 10 Pro but I get an error.


Your system is in selective startup switch it to normal startup. Required system services for WSL are not running while in selective startup. This solution requires elevated permissions on the system.

@SuperKogito - Have somebody with those rights to try it in that case.

That is what I tried but my request got rejected. If someone confirms this solution, I will accept it. Your help is appreciated, thank you!

@SuperKogito - Only you as the author can confirm the answer solves your issue. I know it will work, but since I cannot recreate the issue (or choose not to do so), I can only make the recommendation you try this as your solution. Since you are in a corporate environment throw the issue to your System Administrator to resolve, but this solution requires elevated permissions regardless if you start the required service manually or just start all services.
